# Using multiple CSS rule names with the styled API in Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, styled-components, css-in-js

I'm using Material UI and I want to style a component using multiple rule names with the [styled API](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/#styled-components-api).

Let's say I want to style the [FormLabel Component](https://material-ui.com/api/form-label/#formlabel-api) in blue with the asterisk (required) in red.

With the [Hook API](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/#hook-api) I would do something like that:

```js
import React from 'react'
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles'
import MuiFormLabel from '@material-ui/core/FormLabel'

const useStyle = makeStyles({
  root: {
    color: 'blue'
  },
  asterisk: {
    color: 'red'
  },
})

const FormLabel = ({ children }) => {
  const classes = useStyle()
  return (
    <MuiFormLabel
      classes={{
        root: classes.root,
        asterisk: classes.asterisk
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </MuiFormLabel>
  )
}
```

Can I pass `root` AND `asterisk` to my component using the styled API?

I tried this but it doesn't work

```js
import React from 'react'
import { styled } from '@material-ui/core/styles'
import MuiFormLabel from '@material-ui/core/FormLabel'

const StyledFormLabel = styled(MuiFormLabel)({
  '.MuiFormLabel-root': {
    color: 'blue'
  },
  '.MuiFormLabel-asterisk': {
    color: 'red'
  },
})

const FormLabel = ({ children }) => (
  <StyledFormLabel>{children}</StyledFormLabel>
)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Below is an example of the correct syntax. By default, the top-level keys in the object passed to `styled` are assumed to be CSS property names. By adding `&` at the beginning of the key, it lets `styled` know that you are defining a nested rule. `.MuiFormLabel-root` is unnecessary since the root level is where properties will be applied by default (e.g. `color: "blue"` in the example below). The `&` is a reference to the root-level class, so `& .MuiFormLabel-asterisk` targets descendant elements with the `MuiFormLabel-asterisk` class.

```
import React from "react";
import { styled } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import MuiFormLabel from "@material-ui/core/FormLabel";

const StyledFormLabel = styled(MuiFormLabel)({
  color: "blue",
  "&.Mui-error": {
    color: "purple"
  },
  "& .MuiFormLabel-asterisk": {
    color: "green"
  },
  "& .MuiFormLabel-asterisk.Mui-error": {
    color: "red"
  }
});

const FormLabel = ({ children }) => (
  <>
    <StyledFormLabel required>{children}</StyledFormLabel>
    <br />
    <StyledFormLabel error required>
      {children}
    </StyledFormLabel>
  </>
);
export default FormLabel;
```

[image: Edit FormLabel styled]

Comment: Ryan cogswell, I'm a big fan of yours. where there is a Material-UI question, there is you and your answer.... 

Comment: Ha! Thanks @Rajiv. Yes, I have [answered quite a few](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/material-ui/topusers) over the last couple years.